# Sending hidden HTML form input to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, input, hidden

I have been working on this for hours, and I haven't been able to get it right.

I am using jquery to pull `<address>` from an xml file. From there, I am using it to set that value to that of the hidden input. And from there, I would like to send the hmtl data to the .php file. I have tried everything I can think of and now it's 5:23AM.

Here is my HTML `<input type="hidden" id="SenatorAddress" name="SA" />`

Here is the JS: `

```
     {

        $('#StateSelect').change(function(){
            $('#SenatorSelect').empty();
            var state = $(this).val();
            var select1 = $('#SenatorSelect');
            var SAD = $('#SenatorAddress');
            select1.append('<option value="Select a senator">Select a Senator</option>');
        $(xml).find('member').each(function(){
            if(state == $(this).find('state').text()){
            var fname = $(this).find('first_name').text();
            var lname = $(this).find('last_name').text();
            select1.append("<option>"+fname+"&nbsp"+lname+"</option>");
            var sadress = $(this).find('address').text();
             SAD.append(Sadress);
        }
```

Here is the PHP:

```
The Honorable <?php echo $_GET["senatornames"]; ?><br>
<?php echo $_GET["SA"]; ?><br>
United States Senate<br />
Washington, DC 20510<br />
```

Comment: I don't see `$('#StateSelect').change(function()` bind to any element,  either post complete code n if this is all then check the `var` like set `alert(state);` and see if you get alerts

Comment: That is all the code

Comment: Did you get alert, you can check all `var` by setting alert and see whats going wrong at which point.

Comment: I tried but I didn't get an alert. I just wrote alert(sadress); under it though.

Comment: that means nothing is there, check all var from top to bottom. start from `alert(state);`, `alert(select1);` onwards and if you don't get any alert at all, means your change function not working, where i can see its not bind to any element.

Comment: I see what you mean. I am running a website. Would the alert come as I ran the website?

Comment: No, the alert only triggers with `$('#StateSelect').change(function()`, also check your browser console for error.

Comment: Wow. It works now. I want to thank you both extensively for showing me a new tool that I can check my code with. I'm beyond appreciative.

Comment: Glad to be of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SAD.val(sadress)` instead of `SAD.append(Sadress);`

Comment: what is the output of alert(sadress);

Comment: I did not get an alert. Would the alert appear as I ran the $(#SenateSelect).change function?

Comment: Post you full script. It's very difficult to check it with the partial code. From what I can understand from this, an alert should be shown if the there is an entry for the selected state in the xml .

Comment: as a checking you can try omitting if(state == $(this).find('state').text()){ checking from you script. It should then show an alert for each "member" in the xml. If it shows then check the alert(state ) to see whether its being set. If yes then check the xml for the existence of sadressthat matches the selected state value. 

SAD.val(sadress) should work if you can find sadress for the selected state.

Comment: Your .valc() suggestion actually worked! It was an error on my part. Thank you very much.